# Create element symbol with newcommand and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I want to design a new element symbol. I couldn't add the middle line. How can I add the middle line to my code?

```
\newcommand{\myinn}[1]
{
  \hspace{\spp}
  \tikz[line width=\lw,line cap=round,rotate=#1,baseline=-0.4ex]
  {\draw (-0.5*\w,0.5*\h) -- (-0.5*\w,0.5*\w-0.5*\h)
  arc (-180:0:0.5*\w) -- (0.5*\w,0.5*\h);}
  \hspace{\spp}
}
\newcommand{\myin}{\myinn{270}}
```

[image]

**My code:**

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\h {1.3ex} % cup and cap height
\def\w {1.2ex} % cup and cap width
\def\lw{0.12ex} % cup and cap line width
\def\spp{0.7269ex} % space before and after

\newcommand{\myinn}[1]
{
  \hspace{\spp}
  \tikz[line width=\lw,line cap=round,rotate=#1,baseline=-0.4ex]
  {\draw (-0.5*\w,0.5*\h) -- (-0.5*\w,0.5*\w-0.5*\h)
  arc (-180:0:0.5*\w) -- (0.5*\w,0.5*\h);}
  \hspace{\spp}
}
\newcommand{\myin}{\myinn{270}}
\begin{document}
\[\myin\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do `\def\<one-letter-macro>` in LaTeX, better use `\newcommand*\<one-letter-macr>` instead, and even then you should perhaps pick a longer name.

Comment: Also, what is wrong with using `\in` instead?

Comment: It's not wrong, I just want to know how the code for the middle line is @Skillmon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to add another line to your self drawn symbol. The middle of your cup is at the x-coordinate 0 and you must go from `-.5*\h` to `.5*\h`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\h {1.3ex} % cup and cap height
\newcommand*\w {1.2ex} % cup and cap width
\newcommand*\lw{0.12ex} % cup and cap line width
\newcommand*\spp{0.7269ex} % space before and after

\newcommand{\myinn}[1]
{%
  \leavevmode
  \kern\spp
  \tikz[line width=\lw,line cap=round,rotate=#1,baseline=-0.4ex]
  \draw
    (-0.5*\w,0.5*\h) -- (-0.5*\w,0.5*\w-0.5*\h)
    arc (-180:0:0.5*\w) -- (0.5*\w,0.5*\h)
    (0,-.5*\h) -- (0,.5*\h)
    ;%
  \kern\spp\relax
}
\newcommand{\myin}{\myinn{270}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \myin
  \renewcommand*\h{3.5ex}\myin % <- works for other sizes as well
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very good thank you for your support @Skillmon

Comment: How can I align the symbol vertically up? @Skillmon

Comment: @cufcuf use the `baseline` key in the optional argument of `\tikz`. You can search the `pgfmanual` for an explanation.

Comment: thank you :) @Skillmon